# how to move the number block to the first letter?

Tags: notepad++

Is there a way to move number block to the start of each line in Notepad++? 
such as.

the original log

```
a=1,對  
ba=2,是  
bcd=3,武  
aay=1,今  
aay=2,王
```

the desired log

```
1,a=對  
2,ba=是  
3,bcd=武  
1,aay=今  
2,aay=王
```

Answer (score 2):

Sure.

1. Press **ctrl+h** for search/replace.
2. Activate **Regular Expression** mode (bottom left).
3. Enter in the **Find what** field: `(.*?)=(\d+?),(.*)`
4. Enter in the **Replace with** field: `$2,$1=$3`
5. Finally, click **Replace All**

Presto :)